# What to write in IF condition for Warning Message to delete a row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, warnings

What to write in `if` condition for Warning Message to delete a row in javascript?

```
$scope.removeRow = function(table) {
     $scope.tablerow = [];
     angular.forEach(table.itemTables, function(row, index) {
         var check = row.select;
         if (check == undefined || check == "") {
             $scope.tablerow.push(row);
         } else{
         }
     });
     $scope.ginData.itemTables = $scope.tablerow;
     if(???????==false){
         logger.logError("Please select atleast one item to delete");
     }
 };
```

What should I have to write in place of ??????

I am using eclipse and I want that when I removes a row, this message should be displayed in warning box and when I select one row it would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain a `counter` for the checked items in your loop. Like this:

```
 var check_counter = 0; //Maintains a count of number of items to be deleted
 angular.forEach(table.itemTables, function(row, index) {
     var check = row.select;

     if (check == undefined || check == "") {
         $scope.tablerow.push(row);
     } else{
         check_counter++;
       //Your other logic
     }
 });
```

In the `if` block following the loop just check the value of `check_counter` like so:

```
 if(check_counter == 0){
     //You can be certain that no items were checked otherwise the check_counter variable wouldn't be 0
     logger.logError("Please select atleast one item to delete");
 }
```

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Its not working....although it removes the rows of my project which i have to delete or add.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to write the `if` condition that displays the warning correctly right? So you'd want to show the warning if the user has **not** selected a row, correct?

Comment: yes...i want to show warning when user clicks on delete without selecting any row

Comment: So what problem do you face when you have a `counter` variable like I mention in the question? It just keeps a count of rows that are checked.

Comment: when i am using it , all rows and columns are not showing.

Comment: But I didn't change any functionality of your code. I just added a `counter` that increments in the `else` block. I am not sure how it is causing the rows and columns to hide.

Comment: I guess you tried to copy paste my snippet into your own code. I do not include this line `$scope.ginData.itemTables = $scope.tablerow;` which is why no rows are shown. Try modifying the `for` loop to include the counter and then modify the `if` condition checking on the value of that counter, keeping all the other code unmodified.

Comment: @V.Ahlawat, please mark the answer as accepted so that others in a similar problem might also help. And, I am glad you got your problem sorted :)